# Adjacency data structure to nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-lists, adjacency-list

I have the following model in rails:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id — integer
  # name — string
  # model_id — integer

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Model', foreign_key: 'model_id'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Model', foreign_key: 'model_id'
end
```

I am using adjacency structure, which can have infinite depth. I am on a Postgres database using recursive selects.

What will be the most sane way to get a nested hash of objects? I tried to select instances of `Model` and sort them, yet could not bring this to any usable result.

Lets say I have four `Model` instances saved in my database: `Model_1`, `Model_2`, `Model_3` and `Model_4`. `Model_3` is a child of `Model_2` and `Model_4` is a child of `Model_3`.

Here is an output I am trying to achieve (a nested hash of `Model` instances):

```
{
  #<Model_1...> => {},
  #<Model_2...> => {
    #<Model_3...> => {
      #<Model_4...> => {}
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** Tree is already recovered — either as a CollectionProxy, Relation or any other array-ish data structure. I wan't to sort that tree into the hash of nested hashes.

Comment: Save yourself a few headaches and use ancestry gem.

Comment: MPP is not an option in this case — I need infinite depth with cheap read/write (so closure table and nested tree are not an option either).

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Recover a tree of elements, in the smallest number of queries possible? Are you going to use all of the childrens every time you load the parent, or would it be better to use  lazy loading?

Comment: Lets say that tree is already recovered — either as a CollectionProxy, Relation or any other array-ish data structure. I wan't to sort that tree into the hash of nested hashes.

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: Postgres — it is stated in the second paragraph.

Comment: Ruslan, if I understood right you're basically defining a graph here through an adjacency list stored in DB. When you say that the tree may have infinite depth are you saying that it has cycles/is not a tree or you mean that the tree can have arbitrary depth? If the desired result is to create a nested hash representation of the tree doesn't this mean you need to have infinite memory too (or at least arbitrary large) to store the resulting hash? Can you explain the problem a bit more in this context?

Comment: @bbozo unlimited depth — hypothetically; I meant that a parent can have a single descendant or it can have 10000 descendants. And I can't tell in advance how deep the branch of the tree will go. I am not concerned about implementing the turing machine with infinite memory here but about sorting an array of ActiverRecord models from array into nested hash based on their FK.

Answer (score 1):

I would name it `parent_id` field.

```
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Model"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Model", foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

When you have the hash, you would use `sort` or `sort_by`:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

```
def sort(hash)
  hash.sort { |m1, m2| m1.id <=> m2.id }
  sort(hash.children)
end
```

Comment: Well the tree (which is flattened) is recovered as an Array-like (or enum-like) data structure — i.e. `[#<Model_1...>, #<Model_2...>]`. I can't call `children` method on it out of the box; to do that I first need to sort it into nested structure; and thats what I am aiming towards in first place. Also sorting will just order the objects in array/enum yet I need to nest them.

Answer (score 0):

First, define the ff method inside your Model class:

```
def to_hash
  if children.empty?
    {self => {}}
  else
    {self => children.inject({}) {|hash, model| hash.merge(model.to_hash) } }
  end
end
```

Then do the ff to get the output you want:

```
top_level_models = #code that queries top-level models while eager-loading all nested children
hash_of_nested_models = top_level_models.inject({}) {|hash, ancestor| hash.merge(ancestor.to_hash) }
```

The hash argument that you pass to includes should cover the depth of your nesting. The argument passed to `includes` above will be the nesting for children with a depth of 3 descendants. For as long as you includes all the nested children in your `where` query, generating the hash will not do any more db queries.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works, but this produces N+1 queries; combined with the fact that the tree can be of infinite depth it will very quickly become a bottleneck.

Comment: You did not specify that as a requirement so just came up with something that works. Maybe do an `includes`?

Comment: Rails doesn't support recursive queries; this way `includes` will produce M+1 queries where M is a number of levels of the tree. I think that the only way to keep it in one query is to select and entire tree first, [which is not a problem in my case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYINGG), and only then start sorting it into nested hashes.

Comment: I've just made changes to the code above so that the hash-building code will not make any more DB queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, as stated in the question itself, tree can have infinite depth; so 3 descendants won't do in this case.

Comment: Ruslan, a tree with infinite depth will need infinite memory to store its representation, please see latest comments on OP and elaborate the question

Comment: @Ruslan, you said you already have recovered the tree as a Relation or some other array-like data structure. As long as you eager loaded all the nested children in a query that returns all 'top-level' Models(those without parents), then the solution I provided above should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Getting AR to do this without N+1 queries would be difficult. Will have to write something that works with the data in memory.

You would have to write a custom function which looks something like:

```
 def to_hash
  root_hash = {}
  # Load all the model into memory and into a hash to allow faster access when we have the id
  models = Hash[Model.all.collect {|m| [m.id, m]}]
  # The resultant hash for each child
  models_with_hash = Hash[map.values.collect {|m| [m.id, {}]} ]
  # Stitch them together
  models.each do |id, m| 
    if m.model_id.nil?
      root_hash.merge! m => models_with_hash[m.id]
    else
      # should name model_id to parent_id
      models_with_hash[m.model_id].merge! m => models_with_hash[m.id]
    end  
  end
  root_hash
end
```